# How do I get input from more than 4 wireless controllers on with xboxdrv?

Tags: gamepad, joystick, xbox-360

I'm using xboxdrv on Ubuntu to gather input from Xbox controllers. With wired controllers I can get 4+ controller inputs very easily:

```
xboxdrv --daemon -i 0 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 1 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 2 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 3 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 4 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 5 --detach-kernel-driver
```

But with wireless controllers I can only get up to 4

```
xboxdrv --daemon -w 0 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -w 1 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -w 2 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -w 3 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -w 4 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -w 5 --detach-kernel-driver


-- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------
wireless id must be within 0 and 3
```

What do I need to do to be able to get input from more than four wireless controllers? I know that each wireless receiver can only handle 4 controllers each, but shouldn't it work if I have 2 wireless receivers and eight controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what controllers are available, use:

```
xboxdrv --list-controller
```

It will tell the id and wid. To use the second wireless receiver:

```
xboxdrv --daemon \
                    -i 0 -w 0 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 0 -w 1 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 0 -w 2 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 0 -w 3 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 1 -w 0 --detach-kernel-driver \
  --next-controller -i 1 -w 1 --detach-kernel-driver
```

`-i` is the USB device, `-w` is for the controller on that USB device.